# Configuring Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter Programmatically (Trying Again)

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, common.logging

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011494/configuring-log4netloggerfactoryadapter-programmatically), however the solution was not a programmatic configuration. In this case, a library `Wrapper.dll` is properly configured with `Common.Logging`. A console application `ConsoleApplication1.exe` attempts to implement a `Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter`.

This **works fine**, sending log entries from `Wrapper.dll` to the console.

The `app.config`:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
  </sectionGroup>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<common>
  <logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1211">
      <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
    </factoryAdapter>
  </logging>
</common>
<log4net>... a valid ConsoleAppender ..</log4net>
```

The code within `ConsoleApplication1`:

```
//var properties = new Common.Logging.Configuration.NameValueCollection();
//properties.Add("configType", "INLINE");
//var adapter = new Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);
var c1 = new Wrapper();
```

This **does not work**. It does not send log entries from `Wrapper.dll` to the console. 
The `app.config`:

```
<configSections>
  <!-- <sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
  </sectionGroup> -->
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<!-- <common>
  <logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1211">
      <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
    </factoryAdapter>
  </logging> 
</common> -->
<log4net>... a valid ConsoleAppender ..</log4net>
```

The code within `ConsoleApplication1`:

```
var properties = new Common.Logging.Configuration.NameValueCollection();
properties.Add("configType", "INLINE");
var adapter = new Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);
var c1 = new Wrapper();
```

With the programmatic solution I can successfully use `GetLogger` within `ConsoleApplication1` from either the adapter or from `log4net`, but I cannot get the log events to propagate through from the loggers used in the "Wrapper" library.

Note that in **works fine** I have allowed the xml and commented the programmatic invocation. In **does not work** I have commented the relevant xml and implemented the programmatic code. Note also that this is a trivial example. The real application is trying to use a .NET library that implements `Common.Logging` from Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the adapter you have to set it as the [LogManager's Adapter](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.0.0/api/html/Common.Logging~Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter.html):

```
var adapter = new Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);
Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = adapter;
var c1 = new Wrapper();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.